# Why Does This MySQL Query Return Just 1 Result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is the syntax right?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM productOptions 
 WHERE productOptionsID IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

Have I used IN properly, or should the comma separated values be different?

This is followed by the following code:

```
$optionsresultsql= mysql_query($optionsquerysql) or die(mysql_error());

while($optionssql = mysql_fetch_array($optionsresultsql)) {
  $optionNamesID = $optionssql["optionNamesID"];
  echo $optionNamesID;
}
```

Only one result is shown, even though there are 4 matches in the DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'1,2,3,4'` is a string, which is being converted to an int.  MySQL converts strings to ints by reading up until the 1st non-number character, in your case, the `,`.

So,

```
IN ('1,2,3,4') = IN (CAST('1,2,3,4' AS INT)) = IN (1)
```

The query should just be:

```
productOptionsID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 9):

remove the single-ticks when dealing with INT lookups..

```
"SELECT * FROM productOptions WHERE productOptionsID IN (1,2,3,4)"
```